# How are user opinions compared?

Tags: statistical-significance, likert

Consider a situation where people are asked to rate a product on a scale of 1 to 5.

Product A has a rating of 3.95 based on 15,000 ratings. Product B has a rating of 4.2 based on 1000 ratings.

From the data given, can we determine which product is the preferred one? Is there a direct formula to solve problems of this type? Can anyone explain in layman's terms?

PS: Please retag as appropriate. I couldn't find a relevant tag for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you not have the full distribution of ratings? What you can do with just this information is to assume the standard deviation for both A & B is 2, the most it can be on a 5-point scale, & use that to calculate the standard error of the difference between the two means.

In response to your comment: what you want to know is how well the difference in mean rating between A & B in your sample, $\Delta \bar{x}$, estimates the difference in means in the larger population, $\Delta\mu$. In large samples the difference in means will be Normally distributed to a good approximation; if you know the standard deviation $\sigma$, & having the sample sizes $n_1$ & $n_2$, you can calculate the standard error

$$\sigma_{\Delta\mu}=\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}$$

whcih gives a 95% confidence interval on the difference between means in the population: $$\Delta\bar{x}\pm1.96\sigma_{\Delta\mu}$$

Without the full data-set you don't know the standard deviation, but can use a worst-case value of two to give a conservative confidence interval, i.e. one which will cover the population value with probability of 95% or better. With the complete data-set of course you can estimate the standard deviation (& check the assumption that it's the same in A & B).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your answer. Can you dumb it down? I'm not familiar with any of the terms you have used.
By full distribution of ratings, do you mean the number of people who have rated 1, 2 etc? Yes, I have this data too. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: @GreenNoob - Scortchi has given a pretty thorough guide to testing the difference between two means.  Every term used (except for "mean" itself) has been defined.  You can simply plug your values into the equations given to obtain results.  Can you be specific about what else you are looking for?